# Change Carthage Swift version

Tags: ios, swift, carthage, swift3, xcode8

Is it possible to change Carthage Swift version used to build the frameworks?

I'm trying to migrate my project to swift 3 (on Xcode 8 beta), and the third party libraries are the only thing that stops my project from compiling. 
While using specific branches for swift 3, Carthage throws errors about the new Swift syntax.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select Swift toolchains when building with Carthage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931725/how-to-select-swift-toolchains-when-building-with-carthage)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931725/how-to-select-swift-toolchains-when-building-with-carthage

Comment: @jonahb This question was asked almost 3 years ago, and already have been answered :) (plus this question is older than those you listed)

Comment: As a comment on the accepted answer points out, that response "does not answer the question of how to choose the Swift version." The page I linked to does.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Carthage uses the command line tool `xcodebuild` to build the frameworks. The version of Xcode used by the command line system is determined by the value selected by the tool `xcode-select`

```
Usage: xcode-select [options]

Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example, 
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make).

Options:
  -h, --help                  print this help message and exit
  -p, --print-path            print the path of the active developer directory
  -s <path>, --switch <path>  set the path for the active developer directory
  --install                   open a dialog for installation of the command line developer tools
  -v, --version               print the xcode-select version
  -r, --reset                 reset to the default command line tools path
```

It needs to point to the Developer SDK directory, so you can use `--print-path` to check where it's currently pointing.

```
xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Then to change it just run `sudo xcode-select --switch <path-to-beta-xcode>/Contents/Developer`

Comment: You can also change this using Xcode > Preferences > Locations, then "Command Line Tools"

Comment: Recent Xcode versions support multiple Swift Toolchains. How do I select the Swift version while using the same Xcode version?

Comment: this does not answer the question of how to choose the Swift version

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report on Carthage's GitHub about XCode 8 and broken compatibility. You may want to follow that issue's thread on their repo:

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1440

Another related reported issue in Carthage's repo is: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1445