# Swift3 Framework Module is empty

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift3

Framework Project: https://github.com/twodayslate/SwiftGMP

I built this this project and dragged the SwiftGMP.framework into my iOS application. I can `import SwiftGMP` just fine but I cannot use any of the functions or structs even though they are set to public in the framework. What am I missing? I'm hoping it is just a flag or build setting. The SwiftGMP-Swift.h is being generated.

edit:// I got it working by dragging project into my application and then settings the library path in my main project. Doesn't seem right but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the settings of [this](https://github.com/NeoTeo/SwiftBase58) project which uses SwiftGMP without adding it as a separate sub-project.

Comment: I wasn't using carthage.

Comment: Need to change the version of xcode as well or it won't build properly. `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/` [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867753/change-carthage-swift-version).

Comment: True. I've been setting it from Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Commmand Line Tools and select Xcode 8 from dropdown.