# Carthage requires git 2.3.0 or later

Tags: ios, terminal, ios-charts, carthage

I am using [charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library and trying to run the demo. Before running I have to install the dependencies using Carthage. I goto project folder location and type in terminal:

```
carthage update
```

I got the below error:-

> Carthage requires git 2.3.0 or later.

How to install Carthage decencies and run the above said demo.

[image]

Answer (score 25):

Select `Command Line Tools` to the latest version of Xcode.

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools
```

Open Preferences shortcut : Command + comma <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you have used another Xcode version since last time. You should set **command line tool** again by running the following in terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -s <path to Xcode>/Contents/Developer
```

for example:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help, but I ran into the same issue and found out that xcodebuild is using a different Xcode that I installed.

so you can probably double check which Xcode you are using: 
`xcode-select --print-path`

Here is the original post that helped me solving this issue: 
[Change Carthage Swift version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867753/change-carthage-swift-version)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to install new version of git.

```
brew install git
```

It could say "Target /usr/local/bin/git
already exists. You may want to remove it". I didn't want to remove it and decided only to overwrite:

```
brew link --overwrite git
```

It helped me with the same issue. I hope it will help to someone else.

Comment: after updating OSX i needed mailcore2, use carthage - ok installed carthage, now it says you need git, ok trying to install git - it says you need homebrew, are you kidding me? you need 10 things to get mailcore2? rediculous.