# How to select Swift toolchains when building with Carthage

Tags: xcode, swift2, swift3, carthage

I am creating an iOS app and use Carthage to build external libraries. Since the libraries I use are currently both Swift 2 and Swift 3 I am in a bit of a squeeze. Thus I want to have one Swift 2 branch and one Swift 3 branch for development and then merge them when the libraries are all Swift 3 compatible.

However, I am not able to select which toolchain for build for with Carthage (version 0.18).

Here is the contents of my Cartfile:

```
# Swift 2 libraries
github "stephencelis/SQLite.swift" ~> 0.10.1
github "Haneke/HanekeSwift"

# Swift 3 libraries
#github "stephencelis/SQLite.swift" "swift3"
#github "Haneke/HanekeSwift" "feature/swift-3"
#github "kitasuke/PagingMenuController"
#github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.0
```

This currently builds by using `carthage update`. Here are some output verifying that I am currently using Swift 2:

```
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
$ ls -lh $(which swift)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    18K Jul  8 19:52 /usr/bin/swift
```

Now I want to switch to build with Swift 3. I have multiple toolchains installed in `/Library/Developer/Toolchains`, which is where OSX installs them when I run the installer:

```
$ ls -lh /Library/Developer/Toolchains
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel   204B Sep 30 20:07 swift-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-2016-04-23-a.xctoolchain
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel   238B Sep 30 17:41 swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel   238B Oct  6 20:53 swift-3.0.1-PREVIEW-2.xctoolchain
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    30B Oct  8 12:51 swift-latest.xctoolchain -> swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/
```

Note that I have both Xcode8 and Xcode7 installed:

```
$ ls /Applications/Xcode*
/Applications/Xcode.app:
Contents
/Applications/Xcode8.app:
Contents
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.3.1
Build version 7D1014
```

Now, lets say I have the following scenario:

```
$ cat Cartfile
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.0
$ carthage update --toolchain com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3_0
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.0.1"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/wg/fjk346qs7mx8fhplf8_805wm0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.zfHVn5.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
warning: failed to load toolchain 'com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3_0': Could not find toolchain: com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3_0
```

I just cannot get this to work. So my question is:

**How can I build with Carthage by using another toolchain?**

Here's what I have tried:

1. Changing the symbolic link of `swift-latest.xctoolchain` to other things. Does no difference.
2. Manually adding the toolchains to my `PATH` variable in `.bashrc` like this, but it makes no difference.

   ```
   $ cat ~/.bashrc
   export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-2016-04-23-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/"
   export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/"
   export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0.1-PREVIEW-2.xctoolchain/usr/bin/"
   ```
3. Running the build with `TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3_0 carthage build` and similar, but it makes no difference (still cannot find the toolchain).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of Carthage [0.17](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases/tag/0.17) there is an option `--toolchain` that allows one to specify an exact toolchain ID to use for the build.  Example usage:

```
carthage update --toolchain org.swift.402017072a
```

The ID of the toolchain comes from the key `CFBundleIdentifier` in `Info.plist` file of the toolchain.

Comment: If you have the toolchain installed in Xcode, go to Preferences > Components then hover over the toolchain, click the gear icon and Show in Finder. Once in Finder, right click the `.toolchain` > Show Package Contents and inside you'll find the Info.plist. Open it and copy the CFBundleIdentifier.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using the command `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` or similar, thereby setting the toolchain to the proper one. This will then be the default one used by Carthage. I could not figure out how to select another toolchain when running Carthage.

Comment: The command that you've shared only incidentally selects the swift toolchain by virtue of selecting whatever toolchain is bundled with a version of Xcode. `--toolchain` seems like the answer though I am having difficulty finding details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
export TOOLCHAINS="org.swift.51220191107a"
export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-5.1.2-RELEASE.xctoolchain

carthage update
```

Download Swift toolchain
https://swift.org/download/#releases

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
export TOOLCHAINS="swift"
```

do the trick.