# Why Rswift is not working on Xcode10 with Carthage?

Tags: swift4, xcode10, carthage

Im using Rswift with Carthage. 
Previously I was using Xcode9.4.1 and there was no problem. 
But when I update to Xcode10,
Looks Rswift is not working well.

I have this error

> Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler:

Actually in Xcode build setting, I still using Xcode4. so also wandering why Xcode 10 trying to using Swift4.2.
[Xcode build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqN47.png)

How I can solve this error?

Comment: I tried to writing "$(SRCROOT)/R.generated.swift" to Output Files in Xcode as below, 
https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift/issues/456

but it was not work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **probably** because you've ran `carthage bootstrap` or `carthage update` using a different **toolchain** - obviously because **Xcode 9.4.1** and **Xcode 10** uses different default toolchains.

So, to fix this, just run `carthage bootstrap` and it'll bootsrap correctly.

**By the way:** If you still have Xcode 9.4.1 locally, it may still be using its toolchain. To specify the toolchain, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931725/how-to-select-swift-toolchains-when-building-with-carthage).