# Tell Carthage to build dependency using Swift 3.2.2 (NOT Swift 4.0)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, carthage, swift3.2

I have a project written in Swift 3.2.2 and compiled using XCode 9.1

I have a dependency which is built using Carthage using this command:

`carthage update --platform iOS`

The issue is that Carthage builds the dependency using Swift 4.0 (instead of Swift 3.2.2)

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2

How do I tell Carthage to build my dependency using Swift 3.2.2 so that it can be used in my project?

I don't want to upgrade my project to Swift 4.0 quite yet.

Xcode 9.1 has support for both Swift 3 and Swift 4. So how do I tell Carthage to use Swift 3 when compiling the dependency? I don't want to tell it to use an earlier version of XCode (which I don't have anymore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Carthage Swift version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867753/change-carthage-swift-version)

Comment: @DávidPásztor Xcode 9.1 has support for both Swift 3 and Swift 4. So how do I tell Carthage to use Swift 3 when compiling the dependency? I don't want to tell it to use an earlier version of XCode (which I don't have anymore)

Comment: The same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867753/change-carthage-swift-version)
Please, check it out.

Comment: @lib I don't have multiple version of XCode. I have XCode 9.1 which in theory should be able to compile Swift 3 and Swift 4. Question is how to tell Carthage to have XCode 9.1 use Swift 3.

Answer (score 7):

You say:

1. your project is compiling in Swift 3.2.2
2. your dependency, once resolved and downloaded with Carthage, will be compiling in Swift 4 (since its Build Setting was configured in that way)

with those conditions will be impossible for you resolving the issue: you can't mix Swift 3 and 4 due to this:
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1978

The only thing you can do, for (eventually) fixing the situation is:

---

**Scenario 1**

1. you should find a previous version of the library which is building in Swift 3.2~, if exists
2. on your Cartfile you specify that specific version, eg:

   `github "yourDependency" == x.y.z`

---

**Scenario 2**

1. launch `carthage update --platform iOS`
2. enter inside your dependency folder (`Carthage/Checkouts/yourDependency`) and open the .xcodeproj in order to modify manually this option:

[image]

3. then you might have tons of building problems due to the fact that you are producing a language regression, you can try to fix them (depending by the library if is small or not, it could be possible).
4. if you have solved the dependencies, then launch:

   `carthage build --platform iOS`
5. try to compile your project...

Comment: The swift compiler in Xcode 9 is compatible with both Swift 3 and Swift 4 in the same codebase. They are compiler-compatible.
This rather seems a Carthage bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround for now is to switch to new build system in Xcode. In workspace settings. Or downgrade library version which supports swift 3